# Closing Modal by clicking on body - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog

I have created a modal in my `html` file. I open it by clicking in a button and then I execute a method

This `js` method is the following:

```
  openModal() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
```

and it works. Now what I want to do is to close it by clicking in the body of my website so I have added 3 lines:

```
openModal() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    modal.style.display = "block";

    $(document).on('click', 'body *', function () {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    });
  }
```

The problem seems to be that one click on my mouse is more than one to the computer so it always executes:

`modal.style.display = "block";`

and then with the same click he calls also the click of:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'body *', function () {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    });
```

and it executes it`

I have also created a listener:

```
openModal() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.addEventListener('click', function () {
      $(document).on('click', 'body *', function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      });
    });
  }
```

and it works for the first time but after closing it the listener keeps working so I can not do anything else (it always executes the listener line)

**UPDATE**
I have tried also:

```
  openModal() {
console.log("OpenModal")
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
modal.style.display = "block";
modal.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log("EventListener")
  $(document).on('click', 'body *', function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.removeEventListener('mousemove', function () { console.log("NoEventListener") });
  });
});
```

}

the behavior is the following:

I click on one button, and I call to `openModal` (`console.log("OpenModal")` is working). The modal appears, I click on `body` and the event is triggered (`console.log("EventListener") is displayed`). After it, it does not appear `console.log("NoEventListener")` so `removeEventListener` is not working.

Then, when I click again to the button, I call again to `addEventListener` directly.

What I need is to finish the `eventListener`

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect where is clicked into. Is the click is into `.modal`.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
   if (!$(e.target).parents('.modal').length || ! $(e.target).is('.modal')) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your modal function, you can get the current display style and change display 
according to its value :

```
openModal() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var statut = modal.style.display;
    if (x === "block" {
    modal.style.display = "none";
   }
   else {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Comment: This does not solve it. I know how to open it and close it, but I want to close it by clicking in the body also (the modal has 2 buttons to close it and it works), but I want also to do it by clicking on the body of the whole website